# how to correct set .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

When I try to commit changes to master git shows me unversioned files with .dll,.cash,.. extensions. While googling I found that I must create .gitignore file (like [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)). I have created it and placed in .git project directory.But I still see .dll and other unneccessary files. Then I tryed to [set](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/18739402579/global-gitignore) global .gitignore file (I placed .gitignore file on the same directory with .gitconfig file). Still no changes. How to correct set .gitignore file and what additional actions I must apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not put it into `.git` directory.

Simply copy `.gitignore` file anywhere in your working tree (probably at the root of working tree), and it will work.

You should commit this new `.gitignore` file into your repository, such that other collaborators will automatically use it without having to setup anything.

For more information, read [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).